# Lighttpd - Possible to use .htaccess / directory

Tags: lighttpd

I know most tutorials and topics say that you have to edit lighttpd.conf and add the rewrite rules there, but is it possible to use the .htaccess files per directory utilizing the lighttpd format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, lighttpd does currently not support .htaccess or a similar per directory feature. Lighttpd2 (which is pre-alpha at this moment) however will probably provide such a feature.

If you only want to set per per directory PHP settings you might want to take a look [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/TutorialLighttpdAndPHP#Per-directory-PHP-Config) (or .user.ini which is supported from PHP 5.3.x)